# md5(wordpress) password encryption in c#

Tags: c#, wordpress

I want to authenticate user form asp.net web application. data base used for application is MySQL and password stored in db is in encrypted format which is generated from word press application. i need to encrypted password so that i can compare encrypted password with db password.

my password : Push@123
Encrypted password : $P$BGW0cKLlkN6VlZ7OqRUvIY1Uvo/Bh9/

How to generate this  Encrypted password in c#

Comment: That's a wordpress specific question. How does wordpress generates that hash? What you got reading the documentation?

Answer (score 9):

It took me a while, but here you have working almost 1:1 conversion from php to C#:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Linq;

namespace WordpressHash {
    public class Program {
        private static string itoa64 = "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        public static void Main(string[]args) {
            string StrPassword = "Push@123";
            string expected = "$P$BGW0cKLlkN6VlZ7OqRUvIY1Uvo/Bh9/";

            string computed = MD5Encode(StrPassword, expected);

            Console.WriteLine(StrPassword);
            Console.WriteLine(computed);
            Console.WriteLine("Are equal? " + expected.Equals(computed));
        }

        static string MD5Encode(string password, string hash) {
            string output = "*0";
            if (hash == null) {
                return output;
            }

            if (hash.StartsWith(output))
                output = "*1";

            string id = hash.Substring(0, 3);
            // We use "$P$", phpBB3 uses "$H$" for the same thing
            if (id != "$P$" && id != "$H$")
                return output;

            // get who many times will generate the hash
            int count_log2 = itoa64.IndexOf(hash[3]);
            if (count_log2 < 7 || count_log2 > 30)
                return output;

            int count = 1 << count_log2;

            string salt = hash.Substring(4, 8);
            if (salt.Length != 8)
                return output;

            byte[]hashBytes = {};
            using(MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create()) {
                hashBytes = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt + password));
                byte[]passBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
                do {
                    hashBytes = md5Hash.ComputeHash(hashBytes.Concat(passBytes).ToArray());
                } while (--count > 0);
            }

            output = hash.Substring(0, 12);
            string newHash = Encode64(hashBytes, 16);

            return output + newHash;
        }

        static string Encode64(byte[]input, int count) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 0;
            do {
                int value = (int)input[i++];
                sb.Append(itoa64[value & 0x3f]); // to uppercase
                if (i < count)
                    value = value | ((int)input[i] << 8);
                sb.Append(itoa64[(value >> 6) & 0x3f]);
                if (i++ >= count)
                    break;
                if (i < count)
                    value = value | ((int)input[i] << 16);
                sb.Append(itoa64[(value >> 12) & 0x3f]);
                if (i++ >= count)
                    break;
                sb.Append(itoa64[(value >> 18) & 0x3f]);
            } while (i < count);

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Every hash in the database is encoded using salt and `n` iterations of md5. Brief explanation can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password

Intentionally I have ommited salt generation. But if you will need it in the future, it should start with `$P$` and be at least 12 characters long. Whit this extra method you will be able also to hash new passwords, not only check if hash is correct.

Comment: Great answer.  I used it as a basis for drupal 7 hash.  Here you need to replace MD5 with SHA512 and note that drupal starts $S$.  The second parameter to Encode64 is then 32.  As a final point, within Encode64, I needed to change the if (i < count) to if (i <= count) otherwise my very last character was wrong!

Comment: Nice one, thank you for sharing, saved me a lot of time! :)

Comment: I know this answer is old, but you just saved me tons of work. Had a Java class a while back to do just that using springframework, but moved my project to C#. You just made my life a whole bunch easier

Answer (score 2):

Probably this might do the trick for you

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string StrPassword = "Push@123";
            using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
            {
                string hashPassword = GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, StrPassword);
                Console.WriteLine(hashPassword);
            }
        }
        static string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
        {
            byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            return sBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Hash functions map binary strings of an arbitrary length to small binary strings of a fixed length. A cryptographic hash function has the property that it is computationally infeasible to find two distinct inputs that hash to the same value; that is, hashes of two sets of data should match if the corresponding data also matches. Small changes to the data result in large, unpredictable changes in the hash.

The hash size for the MD5 algorithm is 128 bits.

The ComputeHash methods of the MD5 class return the hash as an array of 16 bytes. Note that some MD5 implementations produce a 32-character, hexadecimal-formatted hash. To interoperate with such implementations, format the return value of the ComputeHash methods as a hexadecimal value.

Source [MSDN: MD5 Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for reply.
but it didnt work for me ,i already try this. it gernrate wrong encryption password

Comment: i tried hashing your password with several hasinging functions on http://www.sha1-online.com/ but none returned the hash you posted in your question - i would assume that your password is salted before it is hashed

Comment: @Nilkhedekar: If you look at MD5 for `Push@123` is `73B0E2415605797A86CDE2883CAEFF27` and not `$P$BGW0cKLlkN6VlZ7OqRUvIY1Uvo/Bh9/` so I am not sure what hash have you used to convert. Please use [Online MD5 Hash Generator](http://passwordsgenerator.net/md5-hash-generator/) to check

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten **crypt_private** php method from class-phpass.php (see **/wp-includes/class-phpass.php** of your wordpress installation) to use it in c#.

[image]

Password is user entered string, setting is user_pass value in wp database of wp_users row.

crypt_private return hash of password. So, **if crypt_private returned value equals setting value, password is correct**.

**This works if you're using php5 and newer** on server with wordpress.

```
    private const string itoa64 = "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    public bool SignIn(string password)
    {
        string foundUserHash = "hash from database (saved password of a user)";

        string hash = Crypt(password, foundUserHash);

        return foundUserHash == hash;
    }

    private string Crypt(string password, string setting)
    {


        string output = "*0";

        if (setting.Substring(0, 2) == output)
            output = "*1";

        string id = setting.Substring(0, 3);

        if (id != "$P$" && id != "$H$")
            return output;

        int count_log2 = itoa64.IndexOf(setting[3]);

        if (count_log2 < 7 || count_log2 > 30)
            return output;

        var count = 1 << count_log2;

        string salt = setting.Substring(4, 8);

        if (salt.Length != 8)
            return output;

        var hash = GetHash(
            GetByteArraysAppended(
                Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes(salt),
                Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes(password)
                ));
        
        do
        {
            hash = GetHash(
                GetByteArraysAppended(
                    hash, 
                    Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes(password)
                    ));
        }
        while (--count!=0);

        output = setting.Substring(0, 12);

        output += encode64(hash, 16);

        return output;
    }

    private string encode64(byte [] input, int count)
    {
        string output = "";
        int i = 0;

        do
        {
            Int32 value = input[i++];
            output += itoa64[value & 0x3f];

            if (i < count)
                value |= input[i] << 8;
            output += itoa64[(value >> 6) & 0x3f];
            if (i++ >= count)
                break;
            if (i < count)
                value |= input[i] << 16;
            output += itoa64[(value >> 12) & 0x3f];
            if (i++ >= count)
                break;
            output += itoa64[(value >> 18) & 0x3f];
        } while (i < count);

        return output;
    }



    private byte[] GetByteArraysAppended(byte[] partOne, byte[] partTwo)
    {
        var parts = partOne.ToList();
        parts.AddRange(partTwo);
        var result = parts.ToArray();

        return result;
    }

    private byte[] GetHash(byte [] bytesToHash)
    {
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        var hash = md5.ComputeHash(bytesToHash);

        return hash;
    }
```